# selenium elements between pseudo not finding

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

One page having following HTMl

```
<div class="call-to-action call-to-action--final">

  <input type="submit" name="complete" value="Complete order" class="btn btn--primary" data-submit-payment="true">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.call-to-action:after, .call-to-action:before
{
content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

Now I want to find this input from selenium but not able to find this, code is

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[contains(@class,'call-to-action--final')]//input")]
        public IWebElement CompleteBtn { get; set; }
```

Also tried

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[contains(@class,'call-to-action--final')]/input")]
        public IWebElement CompleteBtn { get; set; }


 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[contains(@class,'call-to-action--final')]/input[(@value='Complete order')]")]
        public IWebElement CompleteBtn { get; set; }
```

Nothing is working, I think its pseudo elements creating problem, but not able to get rid of it

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input[name='complete']")]
```

or

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input[value='Complete order']")]
```

Comment: It was element's replication issue, I solved it using more sophisticated selector

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer. If you found a different answer, please post it as an answer and accept it for those that come in the future. Thanks!

Comment: this is not definitely answering my question, my problem was in target html design. that needed some tweak to inspect element, and i don't believe that may be reproduce-able .